# Simple Facebook Connect: Access tokens not found

Tags: facebook

I'm not able to configure Simple Facebook Connect v1.5 correctly. The plugins admin panel tells me that:

> No User or Access Token found. Try re-saving this page.
>   Application Access Token not found. Try re-saving this page.
>   Fan Page Access Token not found. Try re-saving this page.

But according to the documentation my configuration should be fine. I double checked `Facebook Application ID`, `Facebook Application Secret` and `Facebook Fan Page ID`

I have also populated the field "Website with Facebook Login - Site URL" with "http://mysite.com"

Not sure if I need to define a value for "App Domains:". OpenSSL v1.0.0c is installed on my server, the URL contains `http://` as outlined in some posts.

**Update**: The SFC plugin also advices to set extended permissions:

> In order for the SFC-Publish plugin to be able to publish your posts automatically, you must grant some "Extended Permissions" to the plugin.
>   To do so, click this button. This will also cause the page to refresh, in order to save the results

This button is not visible to me. When debugging the SFC admin panel with FireBug I see one `oAuth` request to FB is performed. The response has the URL parameter `error=not_authorized` (HTTP 302). Then there are two more requests for `https://www.facebook.com/plugins/login_button.php?...` returning with status codes `302` and `200`. The button is not shown in the admin panel but when I copy the URL to a new tab it shows up correctly, is clickable and I'm able to grant permissions.

[image]

Still the tokens are not available in SFC.

Comment: While it's not "perfect", the official [Facebook plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook/) is probably your best bet moving forward. I don't believe Otto (the maintainer of SFC) came out and said SFC is dead, but he did recommend the official Facebook plugin moving forward.

Comment: Thx for helping! Well the official plugin is quite bad rated and it seems it allows only publishing to the post author's wall. But I'd like that all authors can post to the one and only site-wall. Comment sync from FB to WP is another feature I would need. Even writing my own plugins for SFC could be possible. So I really would like to get it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is browser related (FF 16.02). Using Chrome authorization works fine. But there are still more issues when the Facebook user is not logged in (tokens are not correctly stored locally). So I have settled for the "[Add Link to Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-link-to-facebook/)" plugin.

[image]